# Why trigger click not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

Good day.

I have code:

```
<a class="fancybox iframe" href="http://google.com" id="online_form_a">test</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // add the fancy box click handler here
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#online_form_a").trigger('click');
    },10);
});
</script>
```

This code should click on element `<a>` after 10 seconds, but script not work.

Tell me please where error?

P.S.: see work script can see on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NW5Rj/)

Comment: Triggering a click doesn't redirect you. You have to change `window.location` your self.

Comment: @elclanrs you do not right. trigger should make click on `<a>`

Comment: me not make ridirect. me need click only, that start fancebox

Comment: Then use the fancybox or whatever plugin API, it probably has an `open` method or similar.

Comment: @elclanrs i use plugin **fancybox for wordpress** but i donn`t know how open iframe in window automaticly (

Answer (score 3):

triggering click event means you are calling function binded to the click event of that element..without clicking the element

But there is no click event attached to your element..

Do it like this...

```
<a class="fancybox iframe" href="http://google.com" id="online_form_a">test</a>


$(document).ready(function() {
     // add the fancy box click handler here

     $('a').click(function(){
       window.location.href = "http://google.com";
     });

     setTimeout(function() {
        $("#online_form_a").trigger('click');
     },10000);                //  this value is in milliseconds(1 sec = 1000 ms)
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

not 10, this is milliseconds, so you must use 10000 if you want 10 sec.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/NW5Rj/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // add the fancy box click handler here
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#online_form_a").trigger('click');
    },10000);

    $('a').click(function(){
       alert('Hi'); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I assume you want to automatically redirect to the `a`'s href value, it will not happen using [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

The trigger method will fire the registered event handlers, but the default actions associated  elements may not get triggered.

From Doc

> Although .trigger() simulates an event activation, complete with a
>   synthesized event object, it does not perfectly replicate a
>   naturally-occurring event.

Another choice is [.triggerHandler()](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/), but even this does not cause the default behaviour

> The .triggerHandler() method does not cause the default behavior of an
>   event to occur (such as a form submission).

So the solution is to use `window.location` here

```
window.location = $('#online_form_a').attr('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="fancybox iframe" href="http://google.com" id="online_form_a" >test</a>
```

$(document).ready(function() { 

    // add the fancy box click handler here

    setTimeout(function() {

        location.href = $("#online_form_a").attr('href');

    },1000);

});